# Moving a MapLayer child element programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I have an application with a Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF map, and a few layers added with mapView.Children.Add(layer).
Each of those layers has different types of overlays on it, which are images added with layer.Children.AddChild(image, locationRect).

I want to be able to move, resize and rotate those objects from code (not from xaml which knows nothing about them), but I don't seem to be able to do the first two (rotation being quite simple).

After trial and error and finding some non Microsoft documentation I see that MapLayer.GetPositionRectangle(UIElement) returns the correct location of the object, so it would seem logical that MapLayer.SetPositionRectangle() should set it, but it doesn't and I can't find any examples of anything on the web that programatically moves an object to a new Lat/long.

Is there a way of moving a geographical object on the map, or do I have to either remove it and add it in the right place, or just move it on the canvas in X/Y coords that I have worked out from the lat/long, both of which seem wrong somehow, but this is my first WPF application (normally use forms) and maybe this is the way it is done?

Comment: Turns out when you post you find an answer shortly afterwards. Unlike rotation and anything to do with the object (an image) it didn't update the object after calling SetPosition. Invalidating the object fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

The `Windows-universal-samples` that exist on Microsoft github page can help you. There is an example of MapControl where you can get some ideas.

This sample demonstrates how to use the universal map control (MapControl) in a UWP app.

- MapControl Basics: adjusting the ZoomLevel, Heading, DesiredPtich, and map stype
- Adding points of interest on the map: PushPins, images, and shapes
- Adding XAML overlays on the map
- Showing 3D locations in MapControl
- Showing Streetside experience within MapControl
- Launching Maps using URI Schemes

Url: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl

After this example, if there is more question, post here to solve it.

I think, the best way is getting an model for this XAML, where you can update this properties.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will look through it for assistance to see if there is anything transferable, but at first glance, the map control seems to work in a very different way to the bing map wpf control. (I can't build UWP examples as I don't have the UWP sdk). I am specifically referring to Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF control, I can't use UWP, I need a standard windows application from windows 7 onwards.

Comment: The WPF and UWP map controls are very different and there likely no much that can be transferred between them.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is apply standard transitions to your image through code. you can use the MapLayer.SetPosition to link it to a location on the map. You may want to use an position origin/offset or a margin to align a specific point of the image with the location.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.maplayer.setposition.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.maplayer.setpositionorigin.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.positionorigin.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.maplayer.setpositionoffset.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I tried those. Turns out in the end it the SetPositionX methods were working, but the view hadn't updated, and calling invalidate on the image I was moving updated the whole thing